# How to configure y-axis using seqIplot in R?

Tags: r, traminer

I am trying to configure the y-axis of a sequence index plot using the R-package `TraMineR`, I figured out how to set a global limit for the y-axis which is helpful if you want compare the number of certain sequences between two or more groups as it equalizes the scale. But I did not manage to set the y-axis ticks (as in xtstep). Maybe you can quickly help me out using this example code:

```
library(TraMineR) 
data(mvad)
mvad.alphabet <- c("employment", "FE", "HE", "joblessness", "school",
                      "training")
mvad.labels <- c("Employment", "Further Education", "Higher Education",
                    "Joblessness", "School", "Training")
mvad.scodes <- c("EM", "FE", "HE", "JL", "SC", "TR")

## Define sequence objects
mvad.seq <- seqdef(mvad[, 17:86], alphabet = mvad.alphabet,
                     states = mvad.scodes, labels = mvad.labels, weights = mvad$weight, xtstep = 6)

## Plots
seqIplot(mvad.seq, group=mvad$gcse5eq, withlegend=TRUE, border=NA, xtstep=3, sortv="from.start") ## Default plot
seqIplot(mvad.seq, group=mvad$gcse5eq, withlegend=TRUE, border=NA, xtstep=3, sortv="from.start", ylim=c(0, 400)) ## Plot with custom ylim to compare the number of sequences between groups
```

The default sequence index plot looks like this and makes it very difficult to compare the two groups:
[image: Default sequence index plot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a  `ylim` is given in `seqIplot`, it is used for all groups. To make the plot heights proportional to the weighed number of sequences in each group, the upper `ylim` should be set as the value for to the most frequent group.

```
group <- mvad$gcse5eq
(nseq <- xtabs(mvad$weight ~ group))
(nmax <- max(nseq))
seqIplot(mvad.seq, group=group, withlegend=TRUE,
         border=NA, xtstep=3, sortv="from.start",
         ylim=c(0, nmax) )
```

The tick labels on the y axis are sequence indexes. You can suppress them with by giving `yaxis = FALSE` to `seqIplot`. To display your own labels you can then issue something like (see the help of the `axis`function for details)

```
axis(2, at = c(1, nseq[1]))
```

but in that case you should generate the `seqIplot` separately for each group with `withlegend=FALSE` and organize the plots yourself in a single graphic with `layout` or `par(mfrow=...)`.

Comment: Many thanks for your help! I added some code chunks and a graph to your answer following your suggestions.

Comment: As the edit is stuck, here is the code chunk: layout(matrix(c(1,2,3,3), 2, 2, byrow = TRUE), heights=c(3,1))
seqIplot(mvad.seq[group=="no",], withlegend=FALSE, title="no",
         border=NA, xtstep=3, sortv="from.start", ylim=c(0, nmax), yaxis=FALSE)
axis(2, at = seq(from=0, to=nmax+25, by=50))
seqIplot(mvad.seq[group=="yes",], withlegend=FALSE, title="yes",
         border=NA, xtstep=3, sortv="from.start", ylim=c(0, nmax), yaxis=FALSE)
axis(2, at = seq(from=0, to=nmax+25, by=50))
seqlegend(mvad.seq, ncol=3, position="top", xpd=TRUE)