# How to configure y-axis using seqmtplot in R?

Tags: r, traminer

I am battling to define the y-axis of a plot using seqmtplot. I followed the steps described in a previous post ([How to configure y-axis using seqIplot in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18187308/how-to-configure-y-axis-using-seqiplot-in-r)). However, they do not seem to work for seqmtplot.

The y axis of my plot goes from 0 to 9, so I want it to disply tick marks in intervals of 1 i.e. 0, 1, 2...9

I am running these lines of code.

```
seqmtplot(LSAY.seq, group= , title="Mean time", yaxis=F) 
#axis(2, at=seq(from=0, to=9, by=1))
```

The problem with this is that the starting point of the y axis (i.e. 0) of my plot moved below the bars displaying the data.

Any ideas how could I fix this?

A second associated question is: how can I access the data underlaying the plot produced by seqmtplot?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can control the length of the y axis with `ylim=`. For instance using the `mvad.seq` state sequences defined in [How to configure y-axis using seqIplot in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18187308/how-to-configure-y-axis-using-seqiplot-in-r)

```
seqmtplot(mvad.seq, title="Mean time", ylim=c(0,30))
```

For controlling the tick marks, you need, as already explained in [How to configure y-axis using seqIplot in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18187308/how-to-configure-y-axis-using-seqiplot-in-r), to

1. Disable the plotting of the y-axis with `yaxis=FALSE`
2. Disable the legend with `withlegend=F`.

and you should then plot the legend separately. For example:

```
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
seqmtplot(mvad.seq, title="Mean time", yaxis=F, ylim=c(0,30), withlegend=FALSE) 
axis(2, at=seq(from=0, to=30, by=5))
seqlegend(mvad.seq)
```

The data plotted are accessible with

```
seqmeant(mvad.seq)
```