# How to configure x-axis using seqplot in R?

Tags: r, traminer

Following up on another [question concerning the y-axis of sequence plots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18187308/how-to-configure-y-axis-using-seqiplot-in-r), I am looking for a way to manipulate the x-axis of a sequence plot using the R-package `TraMineR`.

The problem is that `TraMineR` ships with an easy way to adjust the x-axis specifying `xtstep=`. However, this gives no full control over the x-axis as it is not possible to specify the number of ticks, tick labels and the end/limit of the scale independent of each other. In some cases, this might be a nice feature, as you can see using this example code or conferring to the two images below:

```
library(TraMineR) 
data(mvad)
mvad.alphabet <- c("employment", "FE", "HE", "joblessness", "school",
                   "training")
mvad.labels <- c("Employment", "Further Education", "Higher Education",
                 "Joblessness", "School", "Training")
mvad.scodes <- c("EM", "FE", "HE", "JL", "SC", "TR")

## Define sequence objects
mvad.seq <- seqdef(mvad[, 17:86], alphabet = mvad.alphabet,
                   states = mvad.scodes, labels = mvad.labels, weights = mvad$weight)

## Plots
seqIplot(mvad.seq, border=NA, xtstep=1, sortv="from.start") # Many ticks, some tick labels, x-scale shows last month as tick 
seqIplot(mvad.seq, border=NA, xtstep=12, sortv="from.start") # Few ticks, few tick labels, x-scale ends before last 8 months
```

[image: Sequence plot using xtstep=1]
Sequence index plot using xtstep=1

[image: Sequence plot using xtstep=12]
Sequence index plot using xtstep=12

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can disable the x-axis with `axes = FALSE` and then generate your own x-axis. To do that you also have to disable the automatic legend. Here is an example:

```
seqIplot(mvad.seq, border=NA, sortv="from.start", axes = F, withlegend=F) 
axis(1, at=c(1,70)-.5, labels = c("Sep. 93","Jun. 99"))
```

Comment: This works! Where is the default starting point of the x-axis of the `seqplot` function? Could it be, that it is actually `at=c(.5,...)` instead of "1"? Do you happen to know, whether something like minor tick marks for example from the `Hmisc` package work? I cannot produce something reliable with it...

Comment: In order to control ticks and labels independently, I use `axis(1, at=(...), labels=FALSE)` and `axis(1, at=(...), tick=FALSE, labels=val)` at the same time.

Comment: @non-numeric_argument You are right, the ticks and labels are at `c(1,...,nc)-.5`. I have edited the answer accordingly.